# Double query for password when waken up in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen

recently updated to ubuntu 20.04 from ubuntu 18.04. But, when I turn on my laptop from sleep, After writing my password it's again showing the lock screen. I have to click the user's button and I have to write my password twice to unlock the screen

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrading from 19.10 (Xubuntu) to 20.04 (Xubuntu). Sometimes after unlocking the first lock screen I get "stuck" on the second one, nothing I type enters the password field... I'm trying out this solution found on Reddit r/Ubuntu:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ghjztu/double_lock_screen_on_xubuntu_after_upgrading_to/

Comment: It seems that just disabling the screensaver did not cut for me, I had to disable the Lock Screen tab also. Can you expand describing your setup, desktop environment and so on? I think that with the version upgrade for some reason it might have left two session managers running.

Comment: updated from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04